# Usar Model propio para creación de Usuario en Django

Tags: html, python, django

tengo una duda con respecto a la autentificación de usuario y que ésta se pueda realizar a partir de los datos ingresados en un Form que sale de la base de un Model propio.

Verán, tengo un modelo llamado Paciente con lo siguientes datos básicos de prueba (luego lo ampliaré con más atributos)

```
models.py

class Paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField()
    Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    correoElectronico = models.EmailField()
    contrasenha = models.CharField()
    confirmarPass = models.CharField()
```

Para el archivo forms.py

```
class FormularioPaciente(forms.ModelForm):
    nombre = forms.CharField
    Nacimiento = forms.DateField
    correoElectronico = forms.EmailField
    contrasenha = forms.CharField
    confirmarPass = forms.CharField


    class Meta:
        model = Paciente
        fields =('nombre','Nacimiento','correoElectronico','contrasenha','confirmarPass')
```

Usando aquellos campos he logrado poder ingresar pacientes a través del formulario HTML y estos aparecen en la consola de admin en un apartado Paciente.

Con eso ya en mente surge la consulta de mi pregunta del principio. 
¿Cómo puedo lograr que Paciente sea reconocido como Usuario (en la página de admin) para que pueda iniciar sesión en el sistema a través de un login?

Y como consulta extra, ¿puedo utilizar correoElectrónico en vez de un Username para logear?

Muchisimas gracias por leer.

Comment: Saludos lo que debes hacer es extender el model User que es del login de django: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: La parte de logueo con email: https://programadorwebvalencia.com/django-login-con-email-y-contrasena/

Comment: Necesitas extender el `User Model`.
Te dejo un artículo para que sepas las opciones que tienes. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Revisaré los links y comentaré que tal me va.

Comment: Lo mejor seria extender el modelo User de django, aca te dejo un link donde muestran varia manera de hacerlo https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html